# Duplicate Entry Error in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image: I think onesignal is making a conflict here]>Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf.class

Getting this error whenever i try to generate signed apk..

Have tried cleaning code 
Have tried excluding packages

Build.Gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
               "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local 
   value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
      }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
compile 'com.yalantis:contextmenu:1.0.7'
compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
compile 'com.github.mzelzoghbi:zgallery:0.3'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.yalantis:flipviewpager:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }



    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change support library versions to **26.1.0** like below:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Currently, `26.+` uses `26.1.0` and you are trying to use `26.0.0-alpha1` at the same time and it causes duplication.

UPDATE: Update Your project's main gradle like below, add subprojects {...} part to force to use same version of support library.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //maven jcenter etc.
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "26.1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VivekRaj then you need to check other library dependencies if any version conflicts exists. Or check my updated answer

Comment: still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Only removing this line will work:

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'

You have this class duplicated, probably because two (or more) of your libraries are adding the same dependencies.

The first step you must take is to identify which one is interfering. You can try running the `dependencies` task in Gradle, and see what dependencies (or their children) are clashing.

The seconds step will be to tell the Gradle script to exclude that dependency

Comment: Try running the Gradle's `dependencies` task please, and post the output on your question

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: Running this task will not solve your problem, it will hint you in the Gradle Output where the problem is to fix it. When you have the output of running this task, please post it here editing your question, if you can't figure out yourself where the problem is

Comment: ohh sorry ...can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: run `./gradlew dependencies` it will give you the dependecies' tree of your project. you can use `./gradlew app:dependencies` to check just your module

Answer (score 0):

You could add a task to find the duplicates

```
task findDuplicates {
    doLast {
        Map<String, List<File>> map = [:]
        Set<File> jars = configurations.compile.matching {
           include '**/*.jar'
        }.files
        jars.each { File jarFile ->
            zipTree(jarFile).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
                String path = fvd.relativePath.pathString
                List<File> matches = map[path] ?: []
                matches << jarFile
                map[path] = matches
            }
        }
        map.each { String path, List<File> matches ->
            if (matches.size() > 1) {
                println "Found $path in $matches"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `gradle findDuplicates` from command line